# How to explain the upgrade from Particles to Fields between Relativistic QM->QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

It is strange that all books I walked through, non of them explains or motivates how physicists realised that we need to deal with fields instead of particles.

Maybe the closest thing I found is the fact Dirac equation tells us that no singular particles can exists alone, but this still seems to be not a good motivation, why we need to replace wave functions with fields, and some parameters to operators, and indices to variables etc...

Anybody knows how this is realised/developed?

Comment: Have you read Weinberg?

Comment: @Prahar: No, I don't have it, can you explain it please?

Comment: Well, Weinberg spends the first 5 chapters of his book discussing just how fields come into the picture. I cannot do justice to it here. I would suggest that you go read that book for that. It's Steven Weinberg "Quantum Theory of Fields Volume 1".

Comment: @Prahar Oh, so it is a long story, Ok will try to find it, thx.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26960/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

Fields in QFT have a particle content too, so the field is not replacing particles, they are just described in a different way as the possible modes of vibration of the field. Now fields originate in classical physics, most notably with the work of Maxwell. It was then realised that a field solves many problems, like instantaneous interactions at a distance, and provide a *reservoir* of energy and momentum that gets transmitted through waves. This is where the particle interpretation settles in, as the interaction is carried by a quantum intrinsically associated to the field.

Another problem that is solved by fields is that when relativistic effects are considered, the notion of particle is not well-defined. Suppose you want to describe a particle that is decaying. You start with a system described by a particle in a certain state and you end up with a different final state with a different particle content. Hence it is difficult to attach a state to a particle that after a while disappears. What has not changed is the total energy and momentum of the system, and this can be explained as different fields that *communicate* their energy and momentum among themselves through the way the interact with each other.