Ehrenfest's theorem in QFT
In quantum mechanics, for a free particle, we know that the expectation value of its position travels in a straight line in the direction of the expectation value of the momentum (we get this from Ehrenfest's theorem).
In the Klein-Gordon field, I'm trying to understand if an equivalent relation holds. We sort of expect the excitations of the field to propagate in a straight line, but I have a hard time understanding what the equivalent of an expectation value of position would be in QFT since we don't have a position operator.
In other words does Ehrenfest's theorem holds for some definition of the exp.value?
If we can't find such a definition then I do not see what the physical meaning of the momentum operator in the Klein-Gordon field is, since I would expect it to tell us something about the speed and direction of the "average" propagation of a particle.

Can you formulate your question in the form of a question? I guess it is something like "what is the QFT analog of ehrenfest's theorem?"

Based on what I think your question is, I think maybe the answer is something like: the classical field of the path integral obeys the same equation of motion as the quantum field in the canonical heisenberg picture. Maybe.

What about looking at the time evolution of the particle density operator, which is a function of position, for a field with a single particle excitation?

@hft Sure in the Heisenberg picture we get π ~ dφ/dt but I don't see how this can be transformed to exp.values. If we act on both sides with |0> then we will get identically zero...So what's the physical meaning of the Heisenberg equation in QFT?

I'm not saying it can be transformed to expectation values. I'm saying that in the path integral $\mathcal{D}\phi e^{-iS[\phi]}$ formulation the phase is stationary when $\delta S/\delta \phi=0$ which leads to the classical equation of motion $\partial^2\phi+m^2\phi=0$ for  the classical field $\phi$. This equation looks like the heisenberg equation of motion for the quantum field $\partial^2 \hat \phi +m^2\hat\phi=0$. All I'm saying is that those look the same and maybe that is the analog you are looking for. But I guess maybe not.

Anyways, the expectation value with respect to the ground state is going to be zero no matter what (for the usual free field) so that is not going to get you anywhere. Maybe you need to look at expectation value with respect to some other state like a coherent state. I don't know the answer...

I'm thinking that since we know that <0|φ(x)φ(y)|0> ~ e^(-mr) for large r and Δt=0, then there is an effective region that the excitation/particle occupies. This region, remains the same with time, and maybe it is the one that should be considered as evolving in the momentum direction.

Another thought I had was to notice that the momentum operator P is the integral of π grad(φ) dx, and that should be the average momentum of the field, thus grad(φ) behaves as some probability density. Hence, the integral X= φ*grad(φ) dp could be thought of some average/exp. value of position, and if I'm not mistaken, P ~ dX/dt. But then I don't quite understand on what these operators should act...

Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26960/is-there-a-theorem-that-says-that-qft-reduces-to-qm-in-a-suitable-limit-a-theor
