# Two ways of thinking about the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, dirac-equation, second-quantization

My impression is that there are two ways of thinking about the Dirac equation:

1. **Quantum Mechanically:** Here we think of the spinor $\phi$ as a generalization of the Schrodinger wave function  which includes spin. I believe this is the way that  Dirac first thought of it.
2. **Quantum Field Theoretically:** Here  we think of $\phi$  as a ${classical~ field}$, like the electromagnetic $4$-potential  $A$  which we then quantize to produce the quantum field that "electrons are excitations of."

What is the relationship between these two uses of $\phi$?

My impression is that the second way is the "more right" way of thinking about things-- but it is still true that we can consider the electron as a quantum mechanical particle which obeys Schrodinger's equation.  So how do we recover the QM picture from the QFT picture?

Comment: More on reduction from QFT to QM: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26960/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4156/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208615/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is done in detail in Weinberg's QFT book, if you're interested. He shows that the wavefunctions of 1-particle states satisfy the Dirac equation, IIRC.

Comment: @Javier  I'm interested, do you know approx where it is?

Comment: It's in Volume 1, chapter 14: *Bound states in external fields*.