# How light travel in a vacuum or in an empty space?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

How any EM wave travels in a vacuum or an empty space as the propagation of any wave needs a matter or disturbance. Any wave can propagate in a disturbance only. How can it travel in vaccum? 
As wave's propagation needs to have any disturbance.

Comment: Also [How do electromagnetic waves travel in a vacuum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156606/how-do-electromagnetic-waves-travel-in-a-vacuum)

Answer (score 1):

Actually only **mechanical waves** need a **medium** to propagate. Examples of mechanical waves are waves in water and sound waves. Mechanical waves are caused by a disturbance or vibration in matter, whether solid, gas, liquid, or plasma. **Medium** is the matter the waves are traveling through.

The Electromagnetic waves are completely allowed to travel in a vacuum, that's actually one of their most important characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

The propagation of light is described by Maxwell's equation. Two of these equations describe

1. that a change in an electric field generates a magnetic fields, and
2. a change in the magnetic field generates an electric field.

Thus, we are able to picture the propagation of an electro-magnetic field (=light) as being composed of two parts, which generate each another, when they "decay". Thus, these two parts "disturb" each another -- if you like to think of it this way. Thus, they do not need a medium (ether), they only need space and time.